# How to determine whether the request is asking for JSON in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

It's possible to determine whether the request is using Ajax in CodeIgniter. Is there any way in CodeIgniter, similar to Laravel's `Request::wantsJson()`, to determine whether the request is asking for JSON?

Comment: Not sure about JSON, but you can check for AJAX with `input::is_ajax_request()` .. from controller - `$this->input->is_ajax_request()`  You could easily port the laravel method to CI https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Http/Request.php

Answer (score 0):

Well, if there is an application/json content type header
like
'Content-Type application/json'
Then you just get the header like so,

```
$content_type = $this->input->get_request_header('Content-Type', TRUE);
```

Then formulate a conditional response based on the value of $content_type.

Yo.